# Восстановить интерфейс wlan0 в Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux

Сидел в вайфай и инсталлировал программу для интернета. Не помню названия уже. После инсталляции вайфай не находил точки доступа. Как мне восстановить доступ к интернету? Пишет что "Нет доступных сетевых устройств"P.S. изначально вопрос обсуждался [тут][1]  [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/27411/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81-wlan0-%D0%B2-linux-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое - переустановить линукс.

Более сложный путь - разобраться, что происходит. Для этого необходимо проанализировать протокол вывода программы `dmesg`. По нему Вы сможете понять вообще подгружается ли драйвер для wifi. С помощью команд `lsusb` и `lspci` (требуются права su) Вы можете посмотреть видится ли вообще у-во WiFi-адаптера. Если оно не видно, то и драйверу не зачем загружаться - у-ва ведь нет. Далее смотрите что пишут `iwconfig` и `ifconfig`. Плюс еще учтите, что есть несколько способов настройки WiFi и сетевых адаптеров в Линуксе. Один - через ifup, второй - через NetworkManager. Причем последний работает (обычно) через GUI апплет, который должен быть тоже загружен. :-{

Comment: переустанавливать не пришлось. спасибо за ответ.вопрос решен, ответ находится по ссылке в вопросе

Answer (score 0):

1) комманда dmesg напечатала очень много текста, даже понятия не имею что именно там искать.

2) lsusb и lspci напечатали меньше текста но ни одного упоминания об вайфай

3) iwconfig и ifconfig там что-то выводит об вайфай, но распечатки я уже приводил выше со сслыкой на вопрос где я уже задавал.

4) ifup -n wlan0 выводит на экран Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0. Посмотрел на lo и eth0 там для них пишет already configured

ifup -v wlan0 выводит failed to open statefile /var/run/network/ifstate: Permission denied

а вот переустановкой линукса не обижайте. у меня был один раз случай и все советовали отформатировать весь диск, так оказалось что нужно было вообще восстановить MBR или BOOT сектор, точно не помню

Comment: 1. `dmesg` выводит протокол загрузки. В нем видны сообщения от различных драйверов. Они все текстовые и обычно сообщения от одного драйвера помечены определенным образом. Например, при подключении usb-у-ва появляются строчки, начинающиеся с `usb 1-4`2. плохо. Возможно адаптер отсутствует или отключен аппаратно. Если это ноутбук, попробуйте поискать переключатели или клавиатурные комбинации включения WiFi.

Comment: 1. там не все видно в консоли.2. с LiveUsb видны точки вайфай. ну а так - отключение через биос и никаких кнопок. через биос я давненько не отключал.

Comment: 1. или прокручивайте. Или ищите интересующее (напр., `dmesg | grep wifi`). Или сделайте вывод по экранам (`dmesg | more`)

Comment: вывело мне по wlan0:wlan0: link is not ready